# Assert exists().exists returns assert evaluated to false even locator is available in DOM

Tags: karate

First of all Thanks for the Karate-UI. After consuming karate - API, we have started using Karate UI :-)

Let me summarize my question here: I am getting 'assert evaluated to false' from the below code:

```
* match text({}header) == 'header'
* assert exists({}header).exists
```

The first line of the code able to locate the element and compare the text, the second line throws an error for the same locator. Could you please help me sort out this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try 0.9.6.RC3 - we realized `exists()` was so confusing, and changed the API.

Detailed explanation is here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1148

Updated docs are here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-core#optional

So you should do this:

```
* assert exists('{}header')
```

It will help us a lot if you confirm this works. Else please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test

Comment: Thanks for the response. * assert exists('{}header') it worked prefectly as expected in 0.9.6.RC3