# Karate UI Automation test results are not coherent

Tags: karate

My goal is to go to Amazon.com, search for a book and confirm it appears in the results. The results of my assertions are not coherent.

```rb
Feature: Amazon UI automation

  Background:
    * def baseUrl = 'https://www.amazon.com/'

  Scenario: Search for item
    Given driver baseUrl
    And def searchTerm = "Explore It"
    And def searchTermEncoded = "Explore+It"
    # When input("#twotabsearchtextbox", [searchTerm, Key.ENTER])  # ENTER doesn't work ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
    When input("#twotabsearchtextbox", searchTerm)
    And click("#nav-search-submit-text")
    Then locate("div.s-result-list").exists                        # 1) this passes
    And locate("{span}Reduce Risk and Increase Confidence").exists # 2) this passes
    And match driver.url contains "s?k=" + searchTermEncoded       # 3) this fails
```

Assertion 3) doesn't passes. That means Karate doesn't reach the results page of Amazon. I confirmed that is true, because I took a `screenshot()` and Karate was still in the homepage, with the search bar filled.

So why does assertion 1 and 2 pass? The locator of 1) only exists in the results page, there's nothing to match in the home. Also the text of 2) is the full title of the book, which only appears after a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug, probably the same bugs as: [Assert exists().exists returns assert evaluated to false even locator is available in DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62250992/143475)

It's fixed in version [0.9.6.RC3](https://dl.bintray.com/ptrthomas/karate/)

Comment: I replaced my standalone jar with the one I downloaded from [0.9.6.RC3](https://dl.bintray.com/ptrthomas/karate/). I ran the tests again and this time they failed, as expected, with `cannot find locator: div.s-result-list`. It's confirmed that this is a bug and that it will be fixed by 0.9.6.

Comment: Yet I still have a doubt: why do you think Karate can't click the search button and reach the results page? The selectors are all fine... You can copy-paste that code and run on your machine and you will see it happening.

Comment: @dialex don't have time to look at it right now, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @dialex replied in detail :P https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1169#issuecomment-643578019